# Flash Builder Profiler runs out of java heap space trying to expand paths to GCRoot

Tags: flash-builder, out-of-memory, profiler, flashbuilder4

Using Flash Builder 4 on Mac OS X, trying to debug why it seems our Air app is leaking the objects declared in the MXML files, but if I try to expand the Instance in the Object Reference tab of the profiler, it runs for several minutes before throwing a java heap space error.

The heap is already set at -Xmx1024m, setting it to 2048m causes FB to not start at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the trick is that you can have either the Allocation Stack or the Path to GCRoot.

Thank you Adobe for inventing the Heisenberg Uncertainty Profiler.